# dictionary based ngram

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract unigram, bi- and trigram strings that are formed with combination of some of the smaller parts. Is there any possible way to extract them individually without counting the smaller ones when they are part of the larger ones?

```
text = "the log user should able to identify log entries  and domain  log entries"
ngramList = ['log', 'log entries','domain log entries']


import re

counts = {}
for ngram in ngrams:
  words = ngram.rsplit()
  pattern = re.compile(r'%s' % "\s+".join(words),re.IGNORECASE)
  counts[ngram] = len(pattern.findall(text))

print(counts)
```

current program output = `'log':3 ,'log entries':2,'domain log entries':1`

expected output = `'log' : 1 , 'log entries':1, 'domain log entries':1`

Answer (score 3):

You can first sort the ngram list by size and then use `re.subn` to substitute each ngram (from large to small) by an empty string and at the same time count the number of substitutions.

Because you sort from larger to smaller ngram, you ensure that the smaller ones don't get counted 'as part of the larger ones' because you remove those from the string in the loop.

```
import re

s = "the log user should able to identify log entries  and domain  log entries"
ngramList = ['log', 'log entries','domain log entries']
ngramList.sort(key=len, reverse=True)

counts = {}

for ngram in ngramList:
    words = ngram.rsplit()
    pattern = re.compile(r'%s' % "\s+".join(words), re.IGNORECASE)
    s, n = re.subn(pattern, '', s)
    counts[ngram] = n

print(counts)
```

As Wiktor indicates in the comments, you may want to improve your regex pattern though. Now the pattern will also match 'log' in the word 'key logging'. To be sure, you want to wrap the token in word breaks:

```
pattern = re.compile(r"\b(?:{})\b".format(r"\s+".join(ngram.split())), re.IGNORECASE)
```

Comment: This is correct. However, I believe `pattern = re.compile(r"\b(?:{})\b".format(r"\s+".join(ngram.split())),re.IGNORECASE)` will be better since it will not count `log` in `logging`.

Comment: Very true. I added it as a comment.

Comment: BTW, OP seems to be convinced that `r'%s' % "\s+"...` is necessary to make a raw string literal.  This is redundant and `r'%s' %`  can be omitted.